# RadioButton OnCheckChanged is not called

Tags: android, expandablelistview, radio-group

From my `MainView` (`ExpandableListView`)  I get at `RadioButton` defined `child_row.xml`, I set the listener, but `OnCheckChanged` doesn't get called. If I move `RadioButton` to currentview, it does get called.

How can I fix this?

I have ....

1. mainListView.xml //expandableListView
2. group_row.xml    //textView
3. child_row.xml     //has custom radioButton

→

```
 public class Main_ListView extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{ 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 try{
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.mainListView);

      ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
      SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
                new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                        R.layout.group_row,             // Group item layout XML.
                        new String[] { "Group Item" },  // the key of group item.
                        new int[] { R.id.row_name },    // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.
                        createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                        R.layout.child_row,             // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                        new String[] {"Sub Item"},      // Keys in childData maps to display.
                        new int[] { R.id.grp_child}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
                    );
                elv.setAdapter(expListAdapter);       // setting the adapter in the list.

        }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
        }


    final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    final View childview = factory.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);

    answersGroup = (SegmentedRadioGroup) childview.findViewById(R.id.answersGroup);
    if(answersGroup != null)
       answersGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}
@Override   
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    if (group == answersGroup) {
        if (checkedId == R.id.radio0) {
            mToast.setText("One");
            mToast.show();
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio1) {
            mToast.setText("Two");
            mToast.show();
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio2) {
            mToast.setText("Three");
            mToast.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It has to be called, maybe change the condition "if (group == answersGroup)" as testing if 2 objects are identical in java is done with the equals method

Comment: Something is missing when I am getting the ID from different layout - its causing it not to call the method. Like I said, it calls it if I move the radio to currentView's layout. Your check is within the method - but the method isn't getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provided the full code you used. If you later add that inflated *childView* to the `Activity`'s layout then you should provide the main layout to see if you're not somehow blocking the `CheckBox`. If you just inflate the layout then it's normal you don't get the checked event as that *childView* is no where on the screen to be acted upon.

From the looks of your code it seems that you want to set a listener for the `CheckBox` in the child of the `ExpandableListView`. If this is what you want then it's an incorrect attempt and the way to do it is by using a custom adapter for your `ExpandableListView`. There are a lot of tutorials(and questions here) with building a custom adapter and setting listeners to child elements.

Comment: Yes, what I want is listener to checkbox inside the child. Is the custom adaptor the correct way of doing this? Where the actual checkbox listener code go, in the adapter?

Comment: @user1529412 Yes, a custom adapter is the correct way to set the listener. In it's `getChildView()` method inflate your layout and then set the listener of the CheckBox.

Comment: Thanks - Worked like a charm.